# How to load custom data into tfds for keras cyclegan example?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

As per the example in https://keras.io/examples/generative/cyclegan/, a pre-existing dataset has been loaded for implementation. I am trying to add my dataset.

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
data = tfds.folder_dataset.ImageFolder('Images', shape=(256, 256, 3))
ds = data.as_dataset()
```

where 'Images' is the root folder containing two subfolders train and test. train folder containing trainA and trainB , test containing testA and testB.

However, I am unable to understand on how to access trainA , trainB , testA and testB so that it gets accepted by keras cyclegan example.

Answer (score 2):

**Best practice is to write your own tensorflow dataset**

you can do so with the [TFDS CLI](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/cli) (command line interface).

1. Install the TFDS CLI: `pip install -q tfds-nightly`
2. Navigate into the directory of your dataset: `cd path/to/my/project/datasets/`
3. Create a new dataset: `tfds new my_dataset`
4. [...] Manually modify `my_dataset/my_dataset.py` to implement your dataset.
5. Navigate into your new dataset: `cd my_dataset/`
6. Build your new TFDS dataset: `tfds build`

Within your project you then need to import your dataset

```
import my.project.datasets.my_dataset
```

and access it as you would any other tfds dataset:

```
ds = tfds.load('my_dataset')
```

Tensorflow documentation for adding a dataset is to be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/add_dataset).

Comment: In step 4 - what if I have the data manually available in the folder?

Answer (score 1):

Cant write a comment yet but I think this may help some others: kosas Pipeline was working for me, I did optional renamings for my usecase. But I could't load the dataset with the current tensorflow example for cycleGAN (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cyclegan)
I used
`tfds.load("Soiled")`
and I got the errormessage, a 'label' was not found. I found a solution ([TypeError: tf__normalize_img() missing 1 required positional argument: 'label'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70400987/typeerror-tf-normalize-img-missing-1-required-positional-argument-label)) where it states that you have to use
`tfds.load("Soiled", as_supervised=True)`
as otherwise the data is loaded as a dictionary and not as a needed tulpe of (image, label)
This addon worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

I curated/wrote the whole code here

https://github.com/asokraju/Soiled

and added a read me file with specific instructions on how-to. Hope this is helpful

## Custom Tensorflow Input Pipeline for Cycle GANs

### Steps to create the dataset

1. Organize the data set inside a `Data.zip` file

   ```
   trainA
   trainB
   testA
   testB
   ```

   `A` and `B` represents the two classes.
2. Provide the `path` ( of the `Data.zip` file ) in line `28` of `Soiled.py` i.e.,

   ```
   _DL_URLS = Soiled":"C:\\Users\\<user>\\Downloads\\Data_001.zip"}
   ```
3. `cd` into `Soiled` folder and use `tfds build` command to build the data
4. The  Tensorflow record files can be found at `C:\Users\<user>\tensorflow_datasets\soiled`. If needed, these files can be taken elsewhere to use.

### loading the data

There are multiple ways to do it.

1. Import the necessary packages:

   ```
   import tensorflow as tf
   import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
   import sys
   ```
2. Ensure that the path to `Soiled` folder containg the code, NOT the data generated, is accessable to the code. For this I have added the path as follows:

   ```
   sys.path.insert(1, 'C:\\Users\\<user>\\Downloads\\')
   ```
3. Then the data can be loaded using:

   ```
   ds = tfds.load('Soiled')
   ds
   ```

   ```
   {'trainA': <PrefetchDataset shapes: {image: (None, None, 3), label: ()}, types: {image: tf.uint8, label: tf.int64}>,
   'trainB': <PrefetchDataset shapes: {image: (None, None, 3), label: ()}, types: {image: tf.uint8, label: tf.int64}>,
   'testA': <PrefetchDataset shapes: {image: (None, None, 3), label: ()}, types: {image: tf.uint8, label: tf.int64}>,
   'testB': <PrefetchDataset shapes: {image: (None, None, 3), label: ()}, types: {image: tf.uint8, label: tf.int64}>}
   ```
4. test:

   ```
   next(iter(ds['trainA']))
   ```

   ```
   Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
   {'image': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1200, 1920, 3), dtype=uint8, numpy=
   array([[[255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255],
           ...,
           [115, 173, 187],
           [112, 174, 197],
           [108, 172, 199]],

           [[255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255],
           ...,
           [119, 170, 191],
           [115, 165, 192],
           [117, 168, 197]],

           [[255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255],
           ...,
           [109, 145, 179],
           [134, 162, 199],
           [134, 158, 194]],

   ...
           ...,
           [ 72,  95,  67],
           [ 78,  99,  66],
           [ 79,  99,  62]]], dtype=uint8)>,
   'label': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=0>}
   ```

### Steps used to create the folder structure.

1. Install `tensorflow_datasets` package
2. On Command line type `tfds new Soiled`. This will create a `Soiled` folder with file structure

   ```
   checksums.tsv
   dummy_data/
   Soiled.py
   Soiled_test.py
   ```
3. edit `Soiled.py` as needed.

### Possible issues:

1. If it fails to build the pipeline, delete the folder `tesorflow_datasets` folder BEFORE you retry. In windows it can found at `C\users\<user>`.
2. If it gives an error something similar to

   ```
   # tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Could not find directory C:\Users\<user>\tensorflow_datasets\downloads\extracted\ZIP.Users_kkosara_Downloads_Data_18r38_Co4F-G6ka9wRk2wGFbDPqLZu8TekEV7s9L9enI.zip\testA\trainA
   ```

   try changing the `data_dirs` in lines to `path_to_dataset` or something that ensures it has the correct path to the downloaded data.
3. Ensure that the folder structure is proper

   ```
       1. Organize the data set inside a `Data.zip` file 
       trainA
       trainB
       testA
       testB
       A and B represents the two classes.
   ```

   also ensure that there are nothing else except the image files inside the folder.

### Used Resources

1. [How to load custom data into tfds for keras cyclegan example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69221972/how-to-load-custom-data-into-tfds-for-keras-cyclegan-example?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/cli
3. https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/cycle_gan
4. https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/generative/cyclegan.ipynb#scrollTo=Ds4o1h4WHz9U