# TypeError: tf__normalize_img() missing 1 required positional argument: 'label'

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm new to deep learning and I was working with the Tensorflow Oxford Flowers dataset when I ran into an error while normalizing the images. I followed the guide on how to normalize images on the Tensorflow website but the error remains.

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-784175b58712> in <module>
      2     return tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255., label
      3 
----> 4 ds_train = ds_train.map(
      5     normalize_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
      6
```

Followed by

```
TypeError: in user code:


TypeError: tf__normalize_img() missing 1 required positional argument: 'label'
```

I referred to https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/keras_example.

My Code:

```
 #Normalizing the images

def normalize_img(image, label):
    return tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0, label

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
BATCH_SIZE = 128

# Setup for train dataset
ds_train = ds_train.map(normalize_img, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
ds_train = ds_train.cache()
ds_train = ds_train.shuffle(ds_info.splits["train"].num_examples)
ds_train = ds_train.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
ds_train = ds_train.prefetch(AUTOTUNE)

# Setup for test Dataset
ds_test = ds_train.map(normalize_img, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
ds_test = ds_train.batch(128)
ds_test = ds_train.prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
```

Comment: It probably happens because you didn't set the flag as_supervised=True when loading the dataset. If you don't use this flag, the dataset is loaded as a dictionary {image:, lablel:} instead as a tuple (image, label), which cannot be unwrapped in the normalize_img() function with ds_train.map.

Answer (score 1):

It probably happens because you didn't set the flag as_supervised=True when loading the dataset. If you don't use this flag, the dataset is loaded as a dictionary {image:, lablel:} instead as a tuple (image, label), which cannot be unwrapped in the normalize_img() function with ds_train.map

In the example you linked, the dataset is loaded as:

```
(ds_train, ds_test), ds_info = tfds.load(
    'mnist',
    split=['train', 'test'],
    shuffle_files=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    with_info=True,
)
```

Have you removed **as_supervised=True**?

Answer (score 0):

When you define your `normalize_func` function, you define 2 arguments i.e. `image` and `label`. So when you call the function you need to specify what those arguments are. But you do not specify those arguments when you call the function in this line:-

```
ds_train = ds_train.map(normalize_img, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

This is the reason you are getting the error `TypeError: tf__normalize_img() missing 1 required positional argument: 'label'` because you have not specified `label` argument when you call the function.